# Change url after action on other page

Tags: qt, blackberry, qml, cascade

I have 2 folder. In folders are 1 and 1 file.
How I can change url of 1 file using the second file?

assets:

Folder 01

  File_01.qml

Folder 02

  Sheet_01.qml

main.qml

main.qml

```
import bb.cascades 1.4
import "Folder_01"
import "Folder_02"
TabbedPane {
    Menu.definition: MenuDefinition {
        actions: [
            ActionItem {
                onTriggered: {
                    sheet_01.open()
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    Tab {
        id: tab_01
        title: "Tab 01"
        File_01 {
        }
    }
    Tab {
        enabled: false
    }
    attachedObjects: [
        Sheet_01 {
            id: sheet_01
        }
    ]
}
```

File_01.qml

```
import bb.cascades 1.4
Page {
    titleBar: TitleBar {
        title: "File 01"
    }
    WebView {
        id: file_01_WebView
    }
}
```

Sheet_01.qml

```
import bb.cascades 1.4
import "asset:///Folder_01"
Sheet {
    id: sheet_01
    Page {
        titleBar: TitleBar {
            title: "Sheet 01"
            dismissAction: ActionItem {
                title: "Cancel"
                onTriggered: {
                    sheet_01.close()
                    file_01_WebView.url = "http://google.com"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have in file "Sheet_01.qml" error "file_01_WebView.url = "http://google.com"

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed many times here, and the Qt documentation is quite clear about it. 
Due to scope limitation `Sheet_01` item know nothing about elements outside the component.
Following the declarative style of development the component should inform about it's state changes so other items could have reacted to that. For example:

**main.qml**

```
Item {
    id: root
    MyItem {
        id: item1
    }

    MyItem {
        id: item2
        onSomeEvent: item1.doSomeAction();
    }    
}
```

**MyItem.qml**

```
Item {
    id: item
    signal someEvent();
    function doSomeAction() {
        console.log("action executed");
    }
    Component.onComplete: item.someEvent();
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer.
Can you write a complete code please?
And the order of folders?

Very much thank you.

Comment: What complete code? The code above is just to illustrate the idea. If you have difficulty understanding this example I would suggest you starting with [QML book](https://qmlbook.github.io/).

Answer (score 0):

I am happy. I finished user manual for this problem for other people.
This is a functional procedure.

```
// main.qml
import bb.cascades 1.4
import "Folder_01"
import "Folder_02"

TabbedPane {

    Menu.definition: [

        MenuDefinition {

            actions: [

                ActionItem {

                    onTriggered: {
                        sheet_01.open()
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

    tabs: [

        Tab {
            title: "Tab 01"

            File_01 {
                id: file_01
            }
        },

        Tab {
            enabled: false
        }
    ]

    attachedObjects: [

        Sheet_01 {
            id: sheet_01

            onSignal_From_Sheet: {
                file_01.url = "http://google.cz"
            }
        }
    ]
}

// File_01.qml
import bb.cascades 1.4

Page {
    id: page1

    property alias url: file_01_WebView.url

    titleBar: TitleBar {
        title: "File 01"
    }

    WebView {
        id: file_01_WebView
    }
}


// Sheet_01.qml
import bb.cascades 1.4

Sheet {
    id: sheet_01

    signal signal_From_Sheet()

    Page {

        titleBar: TitleBar {
            title: "Sheet 01"

            dismissAction: ActionItem {
                title: "Cancel"

                onTriggered: {
                    signal_From_Sheet()
                    sheet_01.close()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```